# How to unit test getId() method on Symfony2 ORM entity?

Tags: unit-testing, symfony

I want to unit test all my Catalog Entity methods and have a problem with testing getter getId(). 
When I create the Catalog (new Catalog()) there is no Id set and no setId() method!

My first stupid step was to write the mok:

```
public function testGetId()
{
    $category = $this->getMock('\Dimas\CatalogBundle\Entity\Category');
    $category->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getId')
        ->will($this->returnValue(352));
    $this->assertEquals(352, $category->getId());
}
```

But this dummy-test did not tested my entity!

What is the right way to test getId() method?

Comment: What for do you want to test getId() method? If you had some difficult logic in setId method it would make sense to test getId method. But until it's Doctrine's from the box implementation why do you need it to test?

Comment: Like @Alex says, why bother?  Testing simple getter/setters is usually a waste of time.  But if you really wanted to then use reflection http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php, to set the value without having to add a setId method.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make sense unless you have unusual behavior in setter or getter (unless it's more than just a mapping).

Comment: I just start working with Synfony and try to use TDD with 100% unit-testing coverage. Do you permit me not to test that method ? :)

Comment: It's a good use case to start with TDD (simple getter), but only if the value is not generated by Doctrine. As I mention in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have generated IDs (by Doctrine, database auto-increment or something else), you'd be testing the Doctrine (etc.) code.

To test `getId()` properly, you'd have to set ID by yourself, either via constructor (prefered), or setter.

I personally prefer the second approach using UUID. You can find more info [with example here](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid-doctrine#examples).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My Id is mapped as @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")

When I try to set id in class __constructor()
`public function __construct($id = null)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }`
and then in the test
` $category = new Category(352);`
The id is still null. 

Is there a way to set id ?

Comment: It has no sense to set it manually when it's generated. Either remove the "GeneratedValue" annotation or use constructor.

The code you describe should work, could you provide the full code of entity and test case?